# How to detect landmark positions from caricature faces?

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-detection, dlib, keypoint

I have been working on the problem of recognizing faces from given caricatures using the [IIIT-CFW dataset](https://cvit.iiit.ac.in/research/projects/cvit-projects/cartoonfaces.)

So far, I have tried using Python's `dlib` library for detecting landmark points from the cartoon faces. However, it doesn't seem to work well on faces other than real human ones.

Is there any alternative for the same? Any suggestions regarding face alignment and landmark detection would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would train a face landmarking model using dlib's tool on that dataset.  Dlib comes with example programs showing you how to train new models (e.g. http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor.py.html)